# How do I set culture for each execution of an Azure WebJob?

Tags: .net, azure-webjobs, globalization, azure-webjobssdk

I have a queue triggered web job. One of the properties of each message is the culture that should be used. I get resources based on this value.

This is tedious and if possible I would prefer to simply set `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`and have everything managed automatically.

The question: is it safe to set this in the context of a web job that processes messages concurrently where each message could have a different locale?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to resolve this kind scenario would be:

- Create a command which you be storing in queue for processing, Command would include localization information and your actual data.

```js
    {
      "localisation": "en-us",
      "message": "Message for processing"
    }
```

- Write your web job in such a way that it de-serialize your message to understand the type request then you can perform any operation based on the request.
  basically by doing this , you can initiate as many request you want for incoming message.

Hope it helps. Let me know if you need help implementing it.

Comment: This is what I am doing. My question was, is it safe to use the value of "localisation" in your example to set the CurrentUICulture? Is Thread.CurrentThread a separate instance for each message?